# PHP : How to print particular part in the array subscript?

Tags: php, arrays, printing

I have an array result as,

```
$array =    Array(
[subject] => My Subject
[date] => My Date
[id] => My Id    
[message] => *MESSAGE DESCRIPTION*
            *Parts Needed : **********
            *Year : ******
            *Make : **********
            *Model : *******
            *ADDITIONAL INFORMATION*
            *Body Style : *******
            *Vin# : *******
            *Details : *********
            *Engine Liter : ******
            *Engine Size : *********
            *Turbo-Charged : ******
            *Fuel Type : ******
            *Transmission Type : *********
            *CONTACT INFORMATION*
            *Name : *********
            *Address : *********
            *City : ******
            *State : *******
            *Zip : ******
            *Phone : ************
            *Email : *********
```

)

```
$msgArr = explode(PHP_EOL, $array);
$msgArr = array_filter( $msgArr );
$msgArr = array_values( $msgArr );
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $msgArr ) - 1 ; $i += 2 ) {
    $final[ trim( $msgArr[ $i ] ) ] = trim( $msgArr[ $i + 1 ] );
}
echo $final['*MESSAGE DESCRIPTION*'];
```

In this echo statement *message description* is showing as undefined index. how to execute the result from the final array?

Comment: can you try print_r($array); i want see message description struct'

Comment: Is there any delimiter in message property? e.g. "*this is desc*this is info*this is concat" ?

Comment: ALL questions on StackOverflow require a coding attempt and expected result.  Please improve your question with an edit.  StackOverflow is not a free coding service.  I _could_ answer this question with a `preg_match()` call, but your question does not yet qualify for answers.

Comment: If I dont know the lenght of the data how can I proceed? Because it will get different at each everytime. The message is the part from mail. I can't able to guess the length

Comment: What do you mean by "part". Which part, what is some kind of message format? You must provide more info

Comment: pr1nc3's question is why you must post your expected output.  This question is Unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern: `/\*MESSAGE DESCRIPTION\*\s+\K.*?:.*(?:\s+.*?:.*)*/`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Em8OES/2)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e5e60c452229777e933c00a2c0f5715254bcf6f))

```
$array=[
    'subject'=>'My Subject',
    'date'=>'My Date',
    'id'=>'My Id',
    'message'=>'*MESSAGE DESCRIPTION*
*Parts Needed : **********
*Year : ******
*Make : **********
*Model : *******
*ADDITIONAL INFORMATION*
*Body Style : *******
*Vin# : *******
*Details : *********
*Engine Liter : ******
*Engine Size : *********
*Turbo-Charged : ******
*Fuel Type : ******
*Transmission Type : *********
*CONTACT INFORMATION*
*Name : *********
*Address : *********
*City : ******
*State : *******
*Zip : ******
*Phone : ************
*Email : *********'
];
echo preg_match('/\*MESSAGE DESCRIPTION\*\s+\K.*?:.*(?:\s+.*?:.*)*/',$array['message'],$out)?$out[0]:'';
```

Output:

```
*Parts Needed : **********
*Year : ******
*Make : **********
*Model : *******
```

Explanation:

- match `*MESSAGE DESCRIPTION*` (use `\` to make regex interpret the `*` literally.)
- match the newline characters
- `\K` means start the "fullstring match" from this point.
- match lazily until a colon is found, then match the rest of the line.
- repeat this part of the pattern zero or more times.
- the pattern will not match the next heading line because there are no colons in the headings.

See my pattern demo for the formal breakdown of my pattern.